# Strange behavior of htmlspecialchars in my bbcode parser class

Tags: php, bbcode, htmlspecialchars

I wrote a class to parse bbcode but I have a problem when I use the "escape" (function chtml::encode is a wrapper for htmlspecialchars).

MyBBcodeParser: http://snipt.org/srlo0

**Case "BBcodeParser::toHtml($input, false)":**
    `Input: [b]hello[/b] <strong>hello2</strong>`
    `Output: <strong>hello</strong> <strong>hello2</strong>` (bold applied)

**Case "BBcodeParser::toHtml($input, true)":**
`Input: [b]hello[/b] <strong>hello2</strong>`
`Output: &lt;strong&gt;hello&lt;/strong&gt;&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;hello2&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;`

I can not understand the double-escape from the second case...

Comment: It is not supposed to give you such an output in the first case. You didn't close the BBCode tag. It is supposed to replace it with `strong` when the input is: `[b]hello[/b]`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake when I wrote here, in my tests [b] is closed. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you call `BBcodeParser::toHtml($input, true)` with your input then the following is returned:

```
<strong>hello</strong> &lt;strong&gt;hello2&lt;/strong&gt;
```

This is because the `CHtml::encode` is applied before the preg_replace, thus leaving the HTML-code which was generated after the from the BBcode intact, while escaping the HTML code from the input (the seconds `<strong>`, that one around the `hello2`).

Now if you apply `CHtml::encode` again to the result of the "escaped" BBcode it becomes like you posted (notice the `&lt;` in the first strong and the `&amp;lt;` in the second):

```
&lt;strong&gt;hello&lt;/strong&gt;&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;hello2&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;
```

In the first case there seems to be no encoding at all.

Comment: Wait, wait...!

With `BBcodeParser::toHtml($input, true)` the output is:
`&lt;strong&gt;hello&lt;/strong&gt;&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;hello2&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;`.

While I expected **hello** &lt;strong&gt;hello2&lt;/strong&gt;

Comment: @Diego: If I look at the `BBcodeParser` source there is only one "escape" so the other one must be in your part of the code. Can you post that too so we can check that out?

Comment: I have written here because it is not made any kind of encode elsewhere. In fact, if the encode is set to false, there is no other type of encode. The html is written as it is inserted if encode is false.

`$text = "[b]hello[/b] <strong>hello2</strong>";`
`echo BBcodeParser::toHtml($text, true);`
output: `&lt;strong&gt;hello&lt;/strong&gt;&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;hello2&amp;lt;/strong&a‌​mp;gt;`

Comment: @Diego - `echo BBcodeParser::toHtml($input, true)` will output `<strong>hello</strong> &lt;strong&gt;hello2&lt;/strong&gt;`, simply because the `encode` is being executed before the conversion of BBCode to HTML, so it can't affect the `hello` as it is enclosed in non-html tags. Otherwise you're missing something.

Comment: @cthulhu `echo BBcodeParser::toHtml($input, true)` will NOT output <strong>hello</strong>, but it output `&lt;strong&gt;`!

Comment: @Diego - Can you show us a piece of code where you call this method? You can check it in a separate page and you'll see that you're wrong.

Comment: The problem was resolved after restarting the computer, maybe a cache problem, boh! Anyway, thanks :)